# How can I get a div to stick to the bottom of the screen and have the middle content scroll?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a sticky footer, where the footer is ALWAYS visible and docked to the bottom, while the middle content will scroll as content is added to it.  I am using this method of accomplishing that:

```css
/* Reset */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Essentials */

.container {
  display: table;
}

.content {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-body {
  display: table-cell;
}

.scroller {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


/* Aestetics */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.scroller {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <p>This is the header</p>
  </header>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="content-body">
      <div class="scroller">
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p>This is the footer.</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

This works great for Chrome and FF but does not work in IE.  Is there a simple fix for this in IE or does someone know of a better solution?

Comment: Don't be a part of the problem with the IE support. IE should adapt or just go into history.

Comment: I agree idealistically :) but realistically i want it to work for everyone

Comment: I think that IE / Edge users don't really matter. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply consider fixed position like this :

```css
/* Reset */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Essentials */


.content {
  height: 100%;
}

.scroller {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


/* Aestetics */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  padding:20px;
  background:#fff;
  
}

.footer {
 bottom:0;
}
.header {
 top:0;
}

.scroller {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  margin:40px auto;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <p>This is the header</p>
  </header>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="content-body">
      <div class="scroller">
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
        <p>This is the content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p>This is the footer.</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add position fixed to solve this in IE:

```
.header {
  position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%
}
```

Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geprhxxv/15/):

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```